# What exactly is the arborocity?

Tags: graph-theory

What is the arboricity of a graph and how can one compute it for an arbitary graph?

I have checked the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arboricity) however, didn't understand much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the definition is pretty clear.

It's the minimum number of forests you need to cover the edges of the graph.

If the graph is very "dense" you need a lot of them. So it is just another way to measure how dense the graph is.